# How do you store a login session to be used in another route node express passport jwt mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to build a route that will allow the logged in user to change their password. I have a register new user and login route that is working alright, but I don't know how to store that token for future use. My code is as follows

index.js

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const port=8080
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()
const passport=require('passport')
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const authRoutes=require('./routes/auth')
const songRoutes=require('./routes/song')
const playlistRoutes=require('./routes/playlist')

app.use(express.json())
// app.use(passport.initialize());
// app.use(passport.session());

const User=require('./models/User')
//connect mongodb to node app
//mongoose.connect('which db to connect to','connection options (json)')
mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://preezy:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.fi15d52.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
        useNewUrlParser:true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true
    }
)

//setup passport jwt

let opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
//opts.issuer = 'accounts.examplesoft.com';
//opts.audience = 'yoursite.net';
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    console.log(jwt_payload)
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
  
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    // Find and return the user by ID, if needed
    // ...
});


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    //req contains all data for request
    //res contains all data for response
    res.send="Hello World"
})

app.use('/auth',authRoutes)
app.use('/song',songRoutes)
app.use('/playlist',playlistRoutes)

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`App is running on ${port}`)
})
```

auth.js

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const User=require('../models/User')
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')
const {getToken}=require('../utils/helpers')
const passport=require('passport')

router.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    //This code is run when /register is called to post a new user
    //req.body will be json in the form firstname, lastname, email, username
    const {firstName, lastName, email, username, password}=req.body
    //Does a user with this email already exist? yes>error
    const user= await User.findOne({email})
   //email in User schema is equal to req.body email
    if (user) { //user true should make an error
        //status code by default is 200 but we want to make an error
        return res
            .status(403)
            .json({error: 'A user with this email address already exists'})
    } else{//the user does not exist so create a new user
        //do not store password in plain text, convert to a hash (not brown)
        const hashedPw=await bcrypt.hash(password,10)
        const newUserData={firstName, lastName, email, username, password: hashedPw}
        const newUser=await User.create(newUserData)
        //create token to return to the user
        const token= await getToken(newUser)
        //return result to user
        const userToReturn={...newUser.toJSON(),token}
        delete userToReturn.password
        return res.status(200).json(userToReturn)
    }
})

router.post('/login', async (req,res)=>{
    //Get username & pw from user from req.body
    const {username,password}=req.body
    // //Check if user with given username exists if not credentials are invalid
    const user= await User.findOne({username})
    const isPwValid=await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({error:'your credentials are invalid'})
    } else if (!isPwValid){
        return res.status(403).json({error: 'your credentials are invalid'})
    } else if (user&&isPwValid){
        const token= await getToken(user)
        const userToReturn={...user.toJSON(),token}
        delete userToReturn.password
        return res.status(200).json(userToReturn)
    }
})
// Change password route here
router.patch(
    '/profile/:userId/change-password',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    async (req, res) => {
      const userId = req.params.userId; // User ID of the profile you're on
      const authenticatedUserId = req.user._id; // ID of the authenticated user
}
```

I've tested postman and right now authenticatedUserId is returning another user for which I didn't log in. I added in the lines to serialize and deserialize the user to see if that would help but to no avail. Please let me know what I'm missing

Comment: in line const authenticatedUserId = req.user._id; do you want to get _id from database or req object? because to get user from req object you also need to store it first

Comment: @DhruvPatel that's what I'm asking. How do you do that?